# Angularjs filter part of name

Tags: angularjs

I have a jsFiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/GRw64/

I'm new to Angularjs so still finding my feet

My example is a simple ng-init of customer names.

An input field and a ng-repeat to filter the name in the input field against the customer names.

If you type a name in the input field the ng-repeat filters the list to show that name.

If I type Chris the name 'Chris Dave' and 'Chris' appear in the list.

If I change to 'Chris Dave', 'Chris Dave' is still showing in the list but 'Chris' disappears

How can I get a return with all the results that match at least one word in the search.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>

<head>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="" data-ng-init="customers=[{name:'Chris Dave'},{name:'Chris'},{name:'John'},{name:'Paul'}]">

    <div class="container">

        Names:
        <br />

        <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" />

        <br />

        <ul>
            <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name">{{ cust.name }}</li>
        </ul>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also provide a function to the `filter` filter of Angular:

```
ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:filterByName"
```

Then you have to define the function in your controller:

```
$scope.filterByName = function(customer) {
  if(!$scope.name) {
    return true;
  } else {
    var keywords = $scope.name.toLowerCase().split(' ');

    for(var i in keywords){
        var k = keywords[i];
        if (customer.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(k) >= 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

[Working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/PuSK1PdmzbdPlvtp8nBP?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you treat the space-separated keywords as OR relationship, you can create a custom filter to achieve what you need like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.filter('myFilter', function () {
    return function (names, keyword) {
        var listToReturn = [];
        if (keyword === undefined) return names;
        var keywords = keyword.toLowerCase().split(' ');
        angular.forEach(names, function (name) {
            for(var i in keywords){
                var k = keywords[i];
                if (name.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(k) >= 0) {
                    listToReturn.push(name);
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
        return listToReturn;
    };
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9wHe/)**</kbd>

Comment: zsong - I love your solution but I'm having problems understanding it completely. Could you give a brief explanation.